# prevent CRLF conversion in a certain folder

Tags: git, newline

I configured GIT to automatically handle conversion of newline chars between Linux and Windows. But there is a certain folder in my project in which I want GitHub to leave the newline characters as they are (Linux style).

So, I created a .gitattributes file in this folder and put this line inside:

```
*.txt -crlf
```

I pushed in Linux, pulled in Windows, but the file in Windows still has Windows-style newline chars.

I also tried:

```
*.txt -text
*.txt binary
*.txt eol=lf
```

none worked.

What should I do?

Comment: 1) Do files in that folder really have `*.txt` extensions? Note that it's not just some kind of magic: Git uses `fnmatch()` to match the files to operate on when processing `.gitattributes`. 2) With `*.txt eol=lf`, did you try to force-checkout files in that folder? I mean literally delete them and then do `git checkout -- <that_folder>`? That should make Git re-create the files. Does this fix the problem?

Comment: What version of git do you have on the client & server sides?

Answer (score 0):

This is the .gitattributes line that you want:

```
*.txt text eol=lf
```

Additional backward-compatible/alternative options are here: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes.html

Also DO follow kostix's advice to delete and re-checkout the files in the folder to have the proper newlines.